# how to execute callback immediately or force to sequentially - no Promises, no async

Tags: javascript

I have function provided by vendor e.g. i_am_function(x,y,z) which calls callback function "y".

Problem is that I need to execute the function first and then continue with the rest of the code. Unfortunately the environment form vendor doesn't offer option Promises or async/sync (functions undefined :( )

Is there any solution for :
1. to wait until the function finish or
2. to force the callback to be executed immediately.
   (Here I will use my wait function which will check global variable inside the callback. If callback is finished it says OK otherwise it is still in state NO.)

Thx for help.

Comment: You can't get an async result in a non-async function. You can't "wait until the function finish", because if you wait after calling `i_am_function`, the stack is still in your function and nothing else synchronous can execute. If you use a while loop, no variables visible to you can change at all.

Comment: Writing yor next set of operations inside the callback is the only way, if promises and `async/await` is not an option.

Comment: Can you turn your description into a concrete example? It is unclear what you _actually_ need to do here: if you can call `somefunction(x,y,z)` then you clearly already know what `y` is and can run that yourself, first. However, if running `y` relies on data that is derived from `x` and `z`, then data-integrity wise is it "impossible" to run `y` until the code inside that function gets to it, with the appropriate data for it to ingest.

Comment: I need to do save process, within the save function is the vendor somefunction(x,y,z)which calls callback y according parameters x(like which fucntion should be used), z - timestamp.   then callback function y returns the Id. I need to use this Id next in the save function later.

Comment: is it possible that callback function will return value to the  i_am_function and this function will return the same value "higher" like e.g. thrown...